# trying to varify user = 'Admin' and password = 'Admin' using php and a registration page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a registrationPage.php file that has a form to fill up with a User name and a Password which I want to check using a login.php file and echo back and fill a label(in the registrationPage.php) with the message "Password or username are not correct" should the fields are empty or incorrect(UserName and Password are not "Admin").

My problem is that I am unable to update the label in my registrationPage.php upon failing in one of the cases I described.

This is an excerpt from my **registrationPage.php** file containing the login form:

```
 <div  class="container-fluid bg_color8">
        <div class="row alignT">
            <form action=""  method="post">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p> <span >User Name:</span>  <input  type="text" name="euname" id="euname" placeholder="username"></p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p> <span >Password:</span>  <input type="password" name="eupassword" id="eupassword" placeholder="**********"></p>
              </div>

                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-sm-2" value="Log In"  > 
                <br><label id='message'></label >

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and that's my **login.php** file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$message = "Password or username are not correct";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (empty($_POST['euname']) || empty($_POST['eupassword'])) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('message').innerHTML =('$message');</script>";
  }
  else
    if ($_POST['euname'] == "Admin" && $_POST['eupassword'] == "Admin"){
      $username=$_POST['euname'];
      $password=$_POST['eupassword'];
      $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
      header("location: mainPage.php");
    }
    else {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('message').innerHTML =('$message');</script>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: That's because the client is going from `registrationPage.php` and being moved to `login.php` when the form is being submitted. For this to work you need to keep the client on the same page (`registrationPage.php`) I suggest you use `AJAX` to submit/send the form data, once the AJAX receives a response you can use `document.getElementById('message').innerHTM=The_Ajax_Response` rather than having `PHP` output javascript.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve again?

Comment: where are you getting the username and passwords that you are compering?

Comment: If you won't want to use `AJAX` you can always put the `php` script at the top of  **registrationPage.php** and set a variable of `$message='Incorrect login details';` in your if statement then echo that into the html `<label id='message'><?php echo $message;?></label >` this will mean the page will send the data to the same page the client is on but it will cause a refresh/reload, the php will run and if the data is submitted it will then set the `$message` variable for echo.

Answer (score 0):

This can work, but its not recommended to mix PHP and JS the way you are mixing it.

The reason why its failing is because JS expects the elements to already be loaded on the DOM. In your case, the element with ID of `message` is not being reached because it yet does not exist on the DOM on load time. To make this code work you would have to place your php code under your HTML on the same file... However.. this gets really messy and complicated.

Really, what you should do is focus on your structure. You need to decide whether to use PHP on its own, or with AJAX.

If you want to use PHP by itself it shouldn't be a problem, you would just need to take advantage of the sessions and code it something like this:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$message = "Password or username are not correct";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['euname']) || empty($_POST['eupassword'])) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        header("location: registrationPage.php");
    } else {
        if ($_POST['euname'] == "Admin" && $_POST['eupassword'] == "Admin") {
            $username = $_POST['euname'];
            $password = $_POST['eupassword'];
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
            header("location: mainPage.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
            header("location: registrationPage.php");
        }
    }
}
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<div  class="container-fluid bg_color8">
    <div class="row alignT">
        <form action="login.php"  method="post">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p> <span >User Name:</span>  <input  type="text" name="euname" id="euname" placeholder="username"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p> <span >Password:</span>  <input type="password" name="eupassword" id="eupassword" placeholder="**********"></p>
            </div>

            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-sm-2" value="Log In"  >
            <?php if (!empty($_SESSION['message'])) { ?>
                <br><label id='message'><?= $_SESSION['message'] ?></label>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php unset($_SESSION['message']); ?>
```

Comment: Would it not be much easier to just put the `php` at the top of **registration.php** and depending on the outcome of the if conditions set the relevant string for `$message` and echo that into the `<label>`?

Comment: how could I make it so it will evaluate it only if the submit button was pressed and not when the page was loaded?

Comment: Yes, but it I would not recommend to place the greater amount of PHP logic on the same HTML page. This is why the MVC model is so popular. The point is to separate your logic from your views.

Comment: you didn't answer to my question, right now this code will put the label on "Password or UserName is wrong" right when the page is loaded even if the user didn't press the "Log-in" button, I don't want this to happen cause it makes no sense.. how can I prevent it?

Comment: you would need to unset the session once the page is completely loaded. I updated my code with `<?php session_unset(); ?>`

Comment: it would'nt screw up all the session I am trying to establish?

Comment: if there are other sessions then use `unset( $_SESSION['message']);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by using a span at the location you want to show the error. In the below program I combined the **registrationForm.php** and **login.php** in another **php file**. *[(taken from this reference)](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp).*

*The below code also contains some formatting.*

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$subErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if($_POST["euname"] == "Admin") {
    $username=$_POST['euname'];
      $password=$_POST['eupassword'];
      $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
      header("location: mainPage.php");
  }else{
    $subErr = " *Password or username not correct.";
 }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  <span >User Name:</span>  <input  type="text" name="euname" id="euname" placeholder="username"></p>      
  <br><br>
  Password:<input type="password" name="eupassword" action="<>" placeholder="**********" id="eupassword">
 <br><br>
  <span class="error"><?php echo $subErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as NewToJs has suggested you have two ways 1) user php alone and have the php script on top of the page or use ajax if you really want to have the php script on separate page.

**option 1 using php without ajax.**

```
 <?php
session_start();


$message = "";
$errors  = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['euname']) || empty($_POST['eupassword'])) {

        $message = "enter username and password";
        $errors++;
    } else {


        $username = $_POST['euname'];
        $password = $_POST['eupassword'];
    }

    // No errors then continue
    if($errors <=0){

      if ($username === "Admin" && $password === "Admin") {

        $message                = "login correct redirecting";
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
         header("refresh:3; url=MainPage.php"); // redirects
    } else {

        $message = "incorrect username or password";

    }
    }






}
?>




<div  class="container-fluid bg_color8">
        <div class="row alignT">
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"  method="post">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p> <span >User Name:</span>  <input  type="text" name="euname" id="euname" placeholder="username"></p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <p> <span >Password:</span>  <input type="password" name="eupassword" id="eupassword" placeholder="**********"></p>
              </div>

                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-sm-2" value="Log In"  > 
                <br><label id='message'><?php echo $message;?></label >

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

So the proper solution is, unless you wanna use an MVC framework would be to use one file

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    if(//Input is incorrect){
        // Show Form with error message
    }else{
        // Redirect to /profile or whatever
    }
}
else
{
    // Show Form
}
```

Comment: This won't work as the client is on a different page to where the element with the `ID` of `message` is..... Remember `<label id='message'></label>` is on the **registrationPage.php** page but the `php` is run on **login.php** so the client will have navigated to **login.php**

Comment: @Hjort-e this is not the problem. His `echo` is actually right. The variable `$message` will output correctly because it is inside a string formed with double quotes `"" .. "" `.